# Looping in R to Change Classes of Data Frame Columns

Tags: r, for-loop

I have a script I run monthly that preps new data that is delivered to me (*new.data*) to be consistent with historical data so eventually they can be concatenated. The main issue that needs to be handled is adjusting the class of the columns in the data delivery. I have a data frame I load in (*data.format*) that contains the correct column names and classes, and my script works by checking that the column names are the same, then prints out which columns have incorrect classes. I look at the output and manually add code to change the classes. I am now trying to automate this process.

Here is an example using data frames I made up to illustrate the problem, what I have tried, and what I want. At this point in the script I have confirmed that the column names in *new.data* are all correct, and that the columns are in the same order as the rows of *data.format$X*.

```
> data.format 
         X             x
        Name           character 
        Age            factor
        Date           date
        Shoe_Size      numeric

#Give columns with incorrect class
> names(new.data)[which(unname(sapply(new.data,class)) != as.character(data.format$x), arr.ind = F)]
 [1] "Age"                             "Shoe_Size"     



#Give the correct class   
> data.format$x[which(unname(sapply(new.data,class)) != as.character(data.format$x), arr.ind = F)]
 [1] factor    numeric
```

At this point is where I currently manually add code to correct the classes, but I would like to write some code to dynamically adjust the classes. Below is an idea of what I had in mind, which for experienced R users, clearly does not work.

```
   for (field in names(new.data)[which(unname(sapply(new.data,class)) != as.character(data.format$x), arr.ind = F)]) {

      new.data$field = glue("as.",data.format$x[[which(as.character(data.format$X)== field)]],"(new.data$field)")

     }
```

I am actually glad I got around to asking this question today, because it is semi often I run into the problem where I try to make assignments or call functions based on the name of the index of my loop which does not work. I am sure someone on here will have a more "R friendly" way to go about this!

Disclaimer: Pretty novice in this community - edit away if there is a better title or tags, or anything else I can add the the question :D

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I just came up with a pretty rudimentary way to achieve what I want. I'll post it, but I am looking forward to seeing what other answers do!

```
for (i in which(unname(sapply(new.data,class)) != as.character(data.format$x), arr.ind = F)){

  if(data.format$x[[which(as.character(rider.format$X)== colnames(new.data)[[i]])]] == "Date") {
    new.data[,i] <- as.Date(new.data[,i], "%Y-%m-%d")
  }
  if(data.format$x[[which(as.character(data.format$X)== colnames(new.data)[[i]])]] == "factor") {
    new.data[,i] <- as.factor(new.data[,i])
  }
  if(data.format$x[[which(as.character(data.format$X)== colnames(new.data)[[i]])]] == "character") {
    new.data[,i] <- as.character(new.data[,i])
  }
  if(data.format$x[[which(as.character(data.format$X)== colnames(new.data)[[i]])]] == "numeric") {
    new.data[,i] <- as.numeric(new.data[,i])
  }
  if(data.format$x[[which(as.character(data.format$X)== colnames(new.data)[[i]])]] == "integer") {
    new.data[,i] <- as.integer(new.data[,i])
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We can subset the 'new.data' based on the 'X' column, loop over the columns, and the 'x' column from 'data.format' and convert the column to the type

```
nm1 <- data.format$X
nm2 <-  sub("^d", "D",data.format$x)
new.data[nm1] <- Map(function(x, y) match.fun(paste0("as.", y))(x), 
           new.data[nm1], nm2) 
str(new.data)
#'data.frame':  4 obs. of  4 variables:
# $ Name     : chr  "A" "B" "C" "D"
# $ Age      : Factor w/ 4 levels "15","20","25",..: 1 2 3 4
# $ Date     : Date, format: "2014-01-01" "2014-01-01" "2014-01-01" ...
# $ Shoe_Size: num  9 10 5 6
```

#### data

```
data.format <- data.frame(X = c("Name", "Age", "Date", "Shoe_Size"), 
    x = c("character", "factor", "date", "numeric"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)


 new.data <- data.frame(Name = LETTERS[1:4], Age = c(15, 20, 25, 30),
 Date = "2014-01-01", Shoe_Size = c("9", "10", "5", "6"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: Can you explain to me what the purpose of nm2 is please?